# Enforce file tranfer mode to Binary in SFTP from application

Tags: java, unix, sftp, jsch

I am using **com.jcraft.jsch** to trasnfer a .txt file from Unix machine to a remote machine. 
By default its going in Binary format, and remote machine is by default trying to read in ASCII format and facing the CRLF character issues while parsing the file.
I am generating the file on the same Unix machine and using system property (line.separator) as line end.

Now I need to enforce remote machine to read in Binary format.

**Is there any way :**
    **1**. If I can enforce the transfer mode to 'Binary' from my application?
    **2**. If I can tell remote machine to detect and read the file in binary mode (like the way we do using 'Content-Type' in HTTP calls) ?

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong.

JSch library does not even support ascii mode. And most SFTP servers do neither.

So if the application has problem parsing the file, it's more probably because you generate the file in an incorrect format in the first place.